# d3.js Color range for map not displaying as per domain range

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, choropleth

This how I am setting color range for my map

```
    var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([1,1000])
    .range(d3.schemeCategory20b);
```

My values in data which I have set in domain does not exceed 1000, so i have given domain range from 1 to 1000 on setting this range it is not displaying color as expected, like I wanna show my map with colors like domain 
        range [1,50] -> green & [51,250] -> yellow,[251,700] -> dark green & 
        [701,1000] -> yellow
How can I do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Since your range has 20 colours, your domain has to have **19 values**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a threshold scale, if the range has N values the domain has to have N - 1  values.

Therefore, just tell the scale exactly what you've told us in the question:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([50, 250, 700])
    .range(["green", "yellow", "darkgreen", "yellow"]);
```

Here is a basic demo, hover over each rectangle to see its value:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([50, 250, 700])
  .range(["green", "yellow", "darkgreen", "yellow"]);
body.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(51).map(d => d * 20))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => color(d))
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log("value: " + d + ", color: " + color(d))
  })
```

```css
div {
  min-width: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 30% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I am not confused about domain and range Thank you again!! :)

Comment: Elegant demo.. :)